Binders - listing what they are
When calling:
adb shell dumpsys

We get a list of Objects used by different processes:
 Objects
               Views:      171         ViewRootImpl:        3
         AppContexts:       13           Activities:        3
              Assets:       23        AssetManagers:        0
       Local Binders:      681        Proxy Binders:       90
       Parcel memory:       26         Parcel count:       89
    Death Recipients:        9      OpenSSL Sockets:        0
            WebViews:        0

We can also use the below API calls to print out local and proxy binder counts at runtime:
Log.d(TAG, "Local: " + Debug.getBinderLocalObjectCount() + "  Proxy: " + Debug.getBinderProxyObjectCount());

How can we identify which Binder objects (classes) are in the list that produces the count?
I am trying to maintain a complex app (not written by me) and I am struggling to determine where Binders are leaking over time.
It is not until the app exhausts Binders that Android crashes the app and logs a "histogram" like this:
11-29 17:53:43.284932  1016  1059 V Binder  : BinderProxy descriptor histogram (top 10):
11-29 17:53:43.285382  1016  1059 V Binder  :  #1: android.app.IServiceConnection x4160
11-29 17:53:43.285666  1016  1059 V Binder  :  #2: android.view.IWindow x1729
11-29 17:53:43.285827  1016  1059 V Binder  :  #3: android.content.IIntentReceiver x288
11-29 17:53:43.286048  1016  1059 V Binder  :  #4: android.database.IContentObserver x232
11-29 17:53:43.286146  1016  1059 V Binder  :  #5: <cleared weak-ref> x164
11-29 17:53:43.286215  1016  1059 V Binder  :  #6:  x61
11-29 17:53:43.286286  1016  1059 V Binder  :  #7: android.content.IContentProvider x61
11-29 17:53:43.286367  1016  1059 V Binder  :  #8: android.app.IApplicationThread x51
11-29 17:53:43.286434  1016  1059 V Binder  :  #9: android.hardware.display.IDisplayManagerCallback x51

Surely there must be a list of 'handles' that are maintained. Is there any way in which we can relate these handles back to Binder constructors, or hook into an API function so we can log every single Binder creation?
